# SQSEvent doesn't exist in aws-lambda-java-events 1.x and AmazonS3 doesn't exist in aws-lambda-java-events 2.x?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm writing a lambda function that read message from SQS event and and to store the message in S3, but I found that the Java class SQSEvent doesn't exist in the default "aws-lambda-java-events 1.3.0", and when I upgrade it to 2.2.2, it includes the class SQSEvent. However, the class AmazonS3 can't be found anymore.

Could anyone give some tips? Does "aws-lambda-java-events 2.2.2" removed AmazonS3?

Comment: If you want to use class related to S3 event for lambda, this package has class `S3Event`. [Check herer](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-events/2.2.1/source-code)

Comment: Not S3Event, what I need is AmazonS3 client.

Comment: For AmazoneS3 client you need to look for another package. `aws-lambda-java-events` as its name indicates includes only classes related to lambda events. May be you can see [here](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/)

Comment: S3 client is supposed to be within aws-java-sdk-bom 1.11.473

Comment: AmazonS3Client class is available in `aws-java-sdk` but not in `aws-lambda-java-events`. `aws-lambda-java-events` has only events related classes. So you need to use both the packages to be able to use both AmazonS3Client and SQSEvent classes.

Answer (score 2):

update your POM dependency of aws-lambda-java-events to higher version such as : 2.2.6
FYI:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```